# How do you cast a JSON object from a Typescript Map?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, angular7, anonymous-types

So I have a Map like so in a component.

```
 reconciled = new Map<number, boolean>();
```

I subscribe to it changing with a fat arrow function, hooked up to several material checkboxes on their 'change' event:

```
changed = (tranId: number, checked: boolean) => this.reconciled.set(tranId, checked);
```

I liked that I hook this up to an event and if a number is there for the key it updates the value to be true to false if it exists, else adds a new entry.  However I want to pass it to a service as JSON that substitutes in the names I want for the collection. Thus far I have this:

```
const mp: any[] = [];
this.reconciled.forEach(x => mp.push({transactionID: x, reconciled: x}));
```

Obviously this is getting the same boolean twice.  But there is no 'Key' that I can see of the mapped object passed in.  I am more used to C# where I can use a dictionary and then 'Select' whatever I want from that.  I just don't know the syntax but basically I want the behavior of a dictionary but then the ability to anonymously describe the key and value of what I want to call them on a submit method.

Comment: `Map.prototype.forEach()` takes a callback which is called with [three arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach#Description): the value, the key, and the whole `Map`.  Instead of `x => ...` you should be doing `(v, k) => ...`

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I knew it would be something simple.  If only I had hovered over the foreach longer in Visual Studio Code(facepalm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map.prototype.forEach()` takes a callback which is called with [three arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach#Description): the value, the key, and the whole `Map`. Instead of `x => ...` you should be doing `(v, k) => ...`, as in:

```
const mp: any[] = [];
this.reconciled.forEach((v, k) => mp.push({transactionID: k, reconciled: v}));
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.